# How to resize a std::vector based upon one of subclasses?

Tags: c++, vector

I have these classes:

- a Base `class`
- a Child `class` which needs more space than Base.

Something like this:

```
class Base{
};


class Child : Base{
   int something;
};
```

And I define a `std::vector` containing Base class instances.

For example: I want to reserve space instead of using `push_back()` for every Child object. Is there any solution to resize the vector upon the class Child?

Comment: You can't do so! Use pointers (preferably smart pointers) to store references to those objects in your vector.

Comment: The problem is that I want to get a vector from user in C++03. The vector could contain many objects. Thereafter I need efficiency, polymorphism and vectors. It seems completely wrong idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either a vector of `Base` or a vector of `Child`. It can't be both. If you declare a `std::vector<Base>` and attempt to put `Child`s into it, you will slice them and only get the `Base` part of those `Child`s.

If you want polymorphism, you'll have to have a vector of `Base*`. Then the space used for each element of  the vector is just the size of a pointer - that pointer can point at a `Base` or a `Child`.

Comment: Any idea in C++03 rather than pointers? I want to deal with object deletion inside of code.

Comment: @Saeed Well polymorphism works with pointers or references, so you have to use one of them. You could use [`boost::reference_wrapper`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/reference_wrapper.html) or a smart pointer from Boost.